# `window.name` not persistent with file:/// protocol using Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to have **a javascript variable persistent across pages under the same domain**. It works well using `localStorage`. But it does not work for local files using the `file:///` protocol, as this storage is persistent only in a given folder. I tried with `sessionStorage` with the same result.

Instead, I tried to use `window.name` as it is supposed to be persistent in the same window, even when the domain changes. I thought it would thus persist across folders using the `file:///` protocol. But it does not in Firefox 119! For some reason it persists upon reload, but not if I switch forth and back to another page. And it works properly on Chrome 119!

**Is this expected? Is there a workaround?**

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, however what I can tell you is that any web page running from the `file://` location is *heavily* restricted by the browser for fairly obvious security reasons. If you need to do anything more complex than displaying static HTML, use a webserver. IIS comes bundled with Pro SKUs of windows, or you can intsall a docker container with any server you like.

Comment: you're assuming Chrome does this correctly and Firefox is somehow wrong - from the docs `Modern browsers will reset Window.name to an empty string if a tab loads a page from a different domain` - and `file://` locations are considered separate domains as you've found out with local/session storage - your statement `even when the domain changes` is demonstrably incorrect

Comment: @JaromandaX I specifically asked whether this was expected or not. I did not claim it was right or wrong. Clearly, the results are different across browsers, so my question makes sense, I believe. I understand that `file://` would consider locations as separate domains, but apparently Chrome does not work this way.

Comment: `apparently Chrome does not work` ... you could've ended that sentence right there